# Implementation of Unsaved Changes Detection

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, save, savechanges

It seems like three ways to approach detecting unsaved changes in a text/image/data file might be to:

1. Update a boolean flag every time the user makes a change or saves, which would result in a lot of unnecessary updates.
2. Keep a cached copy of the original file and diff the two every time a save operation needs to be checked.
3. Keep a stack of all past operations and push/pop operations as needed, resulting in a lot of extra memory usage.

In general, how do commercial applications detect whether unsaved changes exist and what are the advantages/disadvantages of each approach?  I ran into this issue while writing a custom application that has special saving behavior and would like to know if there is a known best practice.

Comment: "unnecessary updates"? Is it really a concern to write a paltry boolean when you've just applied a filter on the entire image? Even inserting a single character into a Word document does a lot of non-obvious things internally. I doubt writing a flag is relevant compared to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you need an undo/redo system, you need that stack of past operations. To detect in wich state the document is, an item of the stack is set to be the 'saved state'. Current stack node is not that item, the document is changed.

You can see an example of this in Qt QUndoStack( http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qundostack.html ) and its `isClean()` and `setClean()`

For proposition 1, updating a boolean is not something problematic and take little time.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the features you want and the size/format of the files, I guess.

The first option is the simplest, and it gives you just what you want with minial overhead.

The second option has the advantage that you can detect when changes have been manually reverted, so that there is no real change after all (although that probably doesn't happen all too often). On the other hand it is much more costly to make a diff just to check if anything was modified. You probably don't want to do that everytime the user presses a key.

The third option gives the ability to provide an undo-history. You could limit the number of items in that history by grouping changes together that were made consecutively (without moving the cursor in between), or something like that.